# how can I compare the contents on an array in C or c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, comparison, word-count

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to set the contents of an array -*ex: a phrase*- into individual words to be compared.
so when the user enters the data, I can tell how many words of the same length they are.

```
void main(){
     char array[30];
     int length, cont, array_tokens;
     printf("enter a phrase: ");
     scanf("%[^\n]s", array); //or gets(array); which ever one you like
     /*-------------------------
      *******magic happens*******
     ---------------------------*/
     for(int i=0; i<wordcount;i++)
         printf("%d word(s) with %d letters was entered", array_tokens, cont);//some sort of 
     system("pause");                                                      //counter which came 
}                                                                         //with the magic that 
                                                                         //happened before
```

so the result should be:

enter a phrase: **user entered a phrase with similar lentgh words**

1 word(s) with 1 letter was entered

2 word(s) with 4 letters was entered

1 word(s) with 5 letters was entered

3 word(s) with 6 letters was entered

1 word(s) with 7 letters was entered

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Do you care to venture what magic exactly happens?

Comment: I wish I could give more than one up vote per comment i.e. Robert Harvey

Comment: @maverick1989 well about the kind of magic that happens I was thinking on strtok just as robert harvey commented but I don't know exactly how does strtok works :/

Comment: @user2529905 - "I don't know exactly how strtok works" - That's why you read the manual.

Comment: Some other magic that's happening here is that array only has space for 29 chars and a null while the test string is 47 chars long.  That will likely cause a SIGSEGV.  You could use scanf's formatting to prevent that.

Comment: @KristerAndersson thanks to the link provided by RobertHarvey I've managed to separate the string into words, but I haven't managed to get the counter going on

Answer (score 1):

Well, strtok() is one way to solve this problem. If you're aiming for efficiency (you should), you should write a loop which iterates over the letters in the sentence. Count the number of non-space characters encountered since the last white-space, and update the n-letter-word-frequency array whenever you get a white-space. I could've written the code to do this, but I don't want to deprive you of the sense of gratification when you write the working piece of code yourself. :P

Comment: thanks that was helpful!, I'll try to do that, I'm kind of new to programming and I hope I can get some more problem solving capacity as I learn more and more thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to split up the sentence into `tokens` (in this case individual words) by a `delimiter` (in this case a space char ' ').  There are various ways to do that.  A good old-school C method is to use `strtok` as Robert Harvey suggested, which is provided by the C Standard Library.  It works by passing in the string you want to split up, followed by the delimiter at which to split the string.

Then, to count the similar length words, try having integer variables for the different word lengths (or more simply in a sort of frequency array, each index representing a word of that length and its value being a count of their occurrences), looping over all the word tokens, incrementing the corresponding variable when a word of a length is encountered.  To obtain the length of a C-Style string, try `strlen`.

Comment: so to separate the string into single words I could use:
    `tokens=strtok(array," .,-");
     while(token != NULL){
           printf("%s\n", token);
           token=strtok(NULL," .,-"); 
           }`
but how could I do word counting here?

Comment: Loop over each word using a `for` loop, e.g. `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < WORD_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)` .  Each iteration count the length of the current word: `int wordLength = strlen(words[i])`, then increment the corresponding element of the word frequency array, like `wordFrequencies[wordLength]++`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array **count** where **count[i]** is the number of words of length **i**.

```
Set count to 0
Set t to 0
for(int i=0;i<given_phrase.length();i++)
{
 if(given_phrase[i]==' ')
 {
   count[t]++;
   t=0;
 }
 else
 {
   t++;
 }
}
```

For C, simply check for '\0' for end of phrase.
Then you can display results based on count.

Comment: so basically It could be:

`    void main(){`,

`         int count[]={0};`

`         int t=0, length;`

`         char array[30];`

`         char *tokens;`

`         length=strlen(array);`

`         tokens=strtok(array," .,-");`

`         for(int i=0;i<length;i++){`

`             if(array[i]==' '){`

`                count[t]++;`

`                t=0;`

`}`


`             else`

`                 {`

`                  t++;`

`                 }`

`             printf("whatever result");`

`      }`

Comment: @David: I think count array needs a size to be specified.